# gRPC Node: How to set a field that is of another Message type (with multiple types itself)

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc

What I want to achieve is that I have a `.proto` file:

```
message Request {
    Error error = 1;
    bool success = 2;
}

message Error  {
   int32 status = 1;
   string message = 2;
}
```

I compile it so I have the generated files for the client and the service. Then, when I want to set in `grpc`with the  generated `setError()` what do I have to pass to the function? (To match the Error message). An object such  as:

```
{
status: 200,
message: "Success!"

}
```

Does not work... What works is:

```
const error = new Client.Error();
error.setMessage('Something');
error.setStatus(400);
```

and then, if I have a Request message:

```
const request =  new Client.Request()
request.setError(error)
```

That would work, but I was wondering if you could directly pass an object to setError, not having to set every field separately...

Comment: Are you trying to create an object that matches the `Error` message type, or the `Request` message type? Also, you say that what you already tried "does not work". What is going wrong? Is there an error message?

Comment: Edited for clarity :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the generated code from protobuf's javascript compiler forces you to use setters and getters, so you're going to have to set every field one by one.

If you don't like this method, you can always try using the dynamic codegen method instead, which uses protobufjs, and allows you to use plain objects as what you can pass around. There's pros and cons between the two methods, but if you're looking to get rid of the setters, that'd be the way to go.

Answer (score -3):

You may find this guideline on [error handling best practices](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors) to be useful.

In general, errors are created by throwing exceptions. The exception has a status code and a message, which matches your `Error` response.